# Parsing SQL array data to php mail()

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm doing an SQL SELECT to retrieve client data to then generate an email from.
The `$param` that is being parsed to the API is an object:

```js
var param = {
  delivery_id: "string",
  order_id: "string",
}
```

The order_id is then being used to query a second table:

```php
$param = $_REQUEST['param'];
$param = json_decode($param);
$collname = "orders";
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$collname.' WHERE `id` = '.$param->order_id;

$result = $conn->query($sql); 
//$conn is defined externally, and is not the cause of the problem

$aData = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $aData[] = $row;
    }
    sendEmail($aData);
} else {
    echo "Error";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

This first query makes perfect sense, and when the `$aData` is being returned to the front end as a string, it looks like expected; an array of objects (one object).

But when I try to access it in the sendEmail function, it can't access the key values. Same when I try to echo `json_encode($aData[0]->id)` (doesn't work) instead of just echoing `json_encode($aData[0])` (works).

The email is actually sent to the hard-coded BCC-mail, but without any of the values within the array.

```php
function sendEmail(&$aData){

    $to = $aData[0]->contact_email;
    $subject = "".$aData[0]->id;
    $txt = "Something something ".$aData[0]->contact.",
    something something.
    ";
    $headers = "From: email@email.com" . "\r\n" .
    "BCC: email@email.com";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
}
```

How do I access the object keys in the API?

EDIT: question answered by S.DEV. Since data was returned as associative array and not an object, correct targeting syntax was $aData[0]['id'].

Comment: Try `$aData[0]['id']`? If you're fetching using `fetch_assoc`, the items should be received as an associative array and not an object.

Comment: Do `var_dump(json_encode($aData[0]))` and please write the output here.

Comment: Be very careful -- your code is wide open to a SQL injection attack. You should use a prepared statement to add `$param->order_id` to your query. Don't just add it to the end of the SQL string.

Comment: Also be very careful with PHP's `mail()` function. It is also very easy to attack. You should consider using a library like phpMailer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as following:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //$aData[] = $row;
        sendEmail($row);
}
//function sendEmail(&$aData){ 
function sendEmail($aData){
```